# How do I set a KeyEvent on the scene for an object defined in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a very simple program - a rectangle controlled by arrow keys. This is what my FXML file looks like:

```
<Group  fx:controller="default.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <Rectangle fx:id="object" width="20" height="30" />
</Group>
```

And now, I want to add a KeyEvent to this`object`. However, when I do this inside the `initialize()` method in this way: `object.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(...)`, I get a null pointer exception.

I sought but could not find a way to retrieve the Scene object inside the controller. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: You don't have access to the scene in the FXML, and you don't have access to it in the controller unless it's in an event handler (the UI defined in the FXML cannot have been added to a scene when the `initialize()` method is called). Add the key event handler to the scene at the place where you create the scene (`start()` method, or wherever), and call a method on the controller (or model) from the handler.

Comment: @James_D Do you mean that I should create a static Controller handle in the Main class (I create the Scene in the Main class) and then, add this event in the Main class in this way:
`scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> controllerInstance.method());`
?

Comment: Why would you make anything `static` in this scenario? Aren't you loading the FXML in the `Main` class too?

Comment: `Controller controllerInstance = (Controller) loader.getController();`
where `loader` is my FXMLLoader - did you mean this?

Comment: Yes, that's how you get a reference to a controller.